# How to send an empty URI with an HTTP PUT request using curl

Tags: curl

I'm wondering if curl will allow me to send an empty URI with an HTTP PUT request? I need to do this for some testing. When I try this:

```
curl --upload-file testfile.txt http://127.0.0.1:8086/
```

The request is sent with /testfile.txt as the URI, I would like it to be simply /.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try

```
curl --upload-file "" http://127.0.0.1:8086/
```